# NPM passport linkedin login showing 500 if user cancel login

Tags: node.js, npm, passport.js, passport-linkedin

I have implemented npm passport linked social login and it is working fine. But if user cancel the authorisation either they cancel the login on linkedin website. Then it comes back to my website but shows the 500 error.

But as their documentation it should go back to provided failure url. Following my code for failure and success callbacks.

```
app.get('/auth/linkedin/callback', passport.authenticate('linkedin', {
  failureRedirect: '/login'
  }), (req, res) => {
 //here success login goes.
});
```

Also attaching the error screenshot.
[image: 500 Error, When user cancel the login on linkedin website]

Answer (score 3):

After doing search for couple of days I found the solution for the issue:

```
app.get('/auth/linkedin/callback', (req, res, next) => {
 passport.authenticate('linkedin', (err, user, info) => {
  if (err) {
    // failureRedirect
    return res.redirect('/signin');
  }

  if (!user) {
    // failureRedirect
    return res.redirect('/signin');
  }

  req.login(user, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    // successRedirect
    res.redirect('/profile');
  });
 })(req, res, next);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think issue in passport-oauth2 module and user_cancelled_login error is not handle. you can delete this module and paste this https://github.com/anuraggu/passport-oauth2.git link package.json file after that install the module